# Как определить конец посылки по сокетам?

Tags: c++, сокет

Использую сокеты на C++. Читаю данные с помощью функции recv в неблокирующем режиме. Нужно прочитать всю посылку.

Я написал вот так:

```
while (true) {
      int len = socket->recv(request.memory);
      if (len <= 0) break;
}
```

Теперь понимаю, что это совсем не правильно... Как правильно написать?

Comment: "всю посылку" - это как? Я могу отправить одно слово "hello", держать соединение минуту открытым и перед закрытием отправить "world". Этот "hello" будет "всей посылкой"? Или "вся посылка" - это "hello world"?

Comment: Видимо вся посылка это "hello world"

Comment: Т.е. вас интересует не сама посылка, а факт того, что соединение было закрыто передающей стороной, т.е. читать по сокету уже ничего не надо и можно закрывать его на своей стороне. Так получается?

Comment: Посылка очень важна! Но мне нужно получить её полностью... Получается, что либо 1-ое: нужно ждать закрытия соединения и потом обрабатывать запрос, либо 2-ое: обрабатывать запрос параллельно считывания посылки

Comment: Имелось ввиду другое: если вам нужна посылка, то логично обернуть ее в какой-нить протокол, по которому вы сможете понять что сообщение было передано полностью. Тогда соединение может быть постоянно открытым, но посылки вы будете обрабатывать как только они пришли. Если вас интересует весь набор символов, переданных отправителем, начиная с открытия соединения и кончая его закрытием, то здесь посылка не важна, а важен сам факт того, что дальше никаких данных не будет и можно уже полученное смело обрабатывать

Comment: Клиентом является стандартный браузер, протокол HTTP

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26955/discussion-between-bopoh-and-sitev-ru).

Comment: Укажите что за сокеты у вас, на BSD-сокеты это мало похоже.

Comment: @Abyx, протокол HTTP, а там есть `content-length` для этого, но его вроде как можно подделать и отправить там очень произвольное число. Т.е. злоумышленник может отправить кучу запросов с невалидным `content-length` и сервер будет ждать неизвестно чего. Т.к. протокол HTTP, то можно посмотреть как это решается, например, в nginx'е, думаю так будет правильнее

Comment: @Abyx, ну так потому я и пишу про "кучу запросов", особенно когда эти запросы все-таки будут что-то отдавать (например, по 1 байту в 10 секунд из 10М), здесь нужны таймауты на таймауты )) Но эту тему вопрос не затрагивает, поэтому на данном этапе это можно игнорировать

Comment: Я думаю надо ловить fyn или делать протокол на структурах с размером - tlv или чтото подобное

Answer (score 1):

В протоколе TCP нет понятия "размера сообщения", т.к. это потоковый протокол, у него нет ни конца, ни деления на сообщения.

Промежуточные узлы, в т.ч. прокси сервера могут оборвать соединение в любой момент, по этому если `recv` вернула 0, это не означает что мы приняли все данные, конец данных мог просто потеряться.

По этому правильный подход - это либо передавать длину сообщения (как в WebSocket, или Content-Length в HTTP), либо передавать признак конца сообщения (как двойной CR LF в после HTTP заголовков).

Comment: Если `recv` вернул 0, то это безусловно конец (eof), более никакие данные по этому сокету приниматься не будут (но это не обязательно означает, что передавть данные по этому сокету тоже нельзя (см. [man 2 shutdown](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown)))

Comment: @Abyx, так и исходное сообщение могло быть отправлено не полностью, т.е. заголовки посланы одни, а в момент передачи тела запроса страница могла закрыться. [Доки](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) говорят что 0 - это конец, а -1 - ошибка, при этом не каждая ошибка ошибкой является, может быть просто пакет еще не дошел.

Comment: Разобрал логи запросов... Если GET - то ждём двойного перевода строки, если POST - то ждём вначале двойного LF, это мы прочитаем заголовок, парсим, определяем content-length и дальше читаем до следующего двойного LF... Длина тела сообщения должна равняться, как я думаю, content-length